# can not return true inside ajax

Tags: ajax, validation, return-value

i'm creating a form validation and checking the email address if exists to return true or false then validate other fields but it doesn't return true so i can't validate other fields automatically or submit the form validation doesn't complete at all here's the code

```
function check_regemail(){
var email = $("#regemail").val();
if((email.length < 6) ||
(email.indexOf('@',0) < 1) ||
(email.lastIndexOf('@') != email.indexOf('@',0)) ||
(email.lastIndexOf('@') > (email.length - 5)) ||
(email.lastIndexOf('.') > (email.length - 3)) ||
(email.lastIndexOf('.') < (email.length - 4)) ||
(email.indexOf('..',0) > -1) ||
(email.indexOf('@.',0) > -1) ||
(email.indexOf('.@',0) > -1) ||
(email.indexOf(',',0) > -1)){
$("#regemail").css("border","1px solid #F00");
return false;
}
else{
    var ajax = false;
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET","checkmail.php?email="+email);
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
        var response = ajax.responseText;
        if(response.indexOf('exists') !== -1){
            $("#regemail").css("border","1px solid #F00");  
            return false;   
        }
        else{
            $("#regemail").css("border","1px solid #ccc");
            return true;    
        }
    }
}
ajax.send(null);            
}
}


function validate_reg(){
$.each($('form#myform :input'),function(){
$(this).blur().change();
});
if(!check_regemail() || !check_user() || !check_regpass() || !confirm_pass() ||  !check_country() ){
return false;
}
else{
return true
}
}
```

all fields should be validated when i click submit but it doesn't happen and submitting the form doesn't work thought all fields have correct data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because the script does not wait for ajax to finish. I would recommend rewriting your code to validate other fields inside the success callback of ajax:

```
if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
    var response = ajax.responseText;
    if(response.indexOf('exists') !== -1) {
        //email fails, so no need to validate other fields
        $("#regemail").css("border","1px solid #F00");  
    } else {
        //email passes, so validate other fields
        $("#regemail").css("border","1px solid #ccc");

        //validate other fields
        if(!check_user() || !check_regpass() || !confirm_pass() ||  !check_country()) {
           //handle code when validation fails
        } else {
           //code if validation passes
        }
    }
}
```